# Drag n Drop from a DropDownList to a TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to implement Drag n' Drop Functionality in from a `DropDownList` to a `TextBox` in ASP .NET.

I will select and drag 1 item from a DropDownList and drop it on a `TextBox`. I have tried using the jQuery plugin but to no avail.

Please see my markup below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        DropDown();
        StyleButton();

        $('.dragndrop').draggable();

        $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').droppable({
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                ui.draggable.appendTo(this); 
            }
        });
});
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="left" style="width:200px;">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="dragndrop">
                            </asp:DropDownList>                              
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="80px"
                                Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Please what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can drag option elements with native draggable mechanism. What you can do is clone the clicked option into a div representing the option. Then drop the clone on the textbox and suppress the option from the dropdown list. Or you can look for a JQuery plugin doing dropdown manipulations with drag n drop.